# TLS Issue using the Demo site

Tags: c#, docusignapi

Since today, I am receiving the following error message when sending a package:

```
Error calling Login: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

My code

```
StringBuilder authHeader = new StringBuilder(
                $"{{\"Username\":\"{userId}\", \"Password\":\"" +
                $"{password}\", \"IntegratorKey\":\"{IntegratorKey}\"");

            authHeader.Append(
                string.IsNullOrEmpty(senderEmail)
                    ? "}}"
                    : $",\"SendOnBehalfOf\": \"{senderEmail}\"}}");

            Configuration.Default.AddDefaultHeader(
                "X-DocuSign-Authentication",
                authHeader.ToString());

            AuthenticationApi api = new AuthenticationApi();
            return api.Login();
```

Coincidently, today is THE day where TLS1.0 was disables on the demo site of DocuSign. ([source](https://support.docusign.com/articles/000044869))
[image]
While I was aware of that, my application uses the .NET 4.7 framework which will uses TLS1.2 by default. Hence, it should not be a problem
As I use the DocuSign NuGet package found [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.eSign.dll/), I looked in the source code and it uses .NET 4.5 (which uses TLS1.0 unless told otherwise)

I understand that I could implement [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859790/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel#2904963) but, shouldn't it work since my application uses .NET 4.7 ?

Comment: I don't think the community can help you here. It seems that you need to wait until that library is updated

Comment: Sure, but I would have thought that DocuSign would have upgraded the library before removing the TLS1.0 support, at least that's what makes sense to me....

Comment: What .Net 4.7 offers in terms of TLS options is one thing. What `ServicePointManager` defaults to is another. `ServicePointManager`  (up to .Net 4.7.1) negotiates SSL3 and TLS 1.0. You have to explicitly enable the protocol (excluding the others in the process, setting `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`) if you want to be sure that TLS 1.2 is negotiated. Then, it depends on the Server what it can agree upon in the handshake. But if TLS1.2 is not enabled, it will not be negotiated .

Comment: I forgot to mention, you can check what SSL protocol version was negotiated using this: [Which TLS version was negotiated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48589590/which-tls-version-was-negotiated?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: @Jimi: Thanks but in case you didn't notice, I am the one who originally asked for this question "Which Tls version was negotiated" so I am aware of that. The answer would work only if I were to modify the DocuSign SDK which I am not interested to do as I want to use the official one

Comment: HA! That's hilarious! Sorry, I didn't check the "OP" nick before commenting :). Have you verified this, setting and non-setting the ServicePointManager protocol?

Comment: Yeah no worries :-) Yep I tried setting the ServicePointManagerProtocol and while it worked well, I originally thought that having my program use .NET 4.7 would lead to use TLS1.2 automatically. And it seems to be bad practice as it means that I will have to change my code again when I want to use TLS 1.3

Comment: Yes, well, we all thought that. TLS 1.3 should be different in many ways. More self-aware (hoping that the implementation will be as well).

Comment: Btw, if you haven't noticed, I've updated the "linked answer", because it wasn't  getting right the compressed streams (`GzipStream` and `DeflateStream`). And, sadly, I haven't found any other way to get to the SSLProtocol without reflection. In a way or another, you always bang your head against a non-public .Net class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLS 1.1 or above is required for all DocuSign APIs and endpoints.
All our libraries now support TLS 1.2 including the the DocuSign eSign C# Nuget package.
See here - https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/End-of-TLS-1-0-and-weak-cipher-support

Comment: Can you state the official source of your statement ?

Comment: You are correct. I revised my answer to reflect that.