# When should I use var and when should I use string, ulong, int, etc

Tags: c#, .net

What is the "proper" way to use

```
var x = "text";
```

or

```
string x = "text";
```

Does it matter which I use? Is there a "standard" way people usually do it? I only ask because sometimes Rider suggests that I use [var](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZlpW.png).

Comment: It doesn't affect compile time, for one. Really, just use it when you feel comfortable. It also makes code looks cleaner. For example, If I have a `Dictionary<CustomClass<int>, boolean> dictionary`, I don't want to have to explicitly type that every single time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few times where you must use an explicit type, and instances where you must use `var`.

### Must use explicit type:

If you declare a variable without initializing it, or, if you want to initialize a variable explicitly as `null`

```
 string myString;
 int i;
 string someString=null;
 DateTime? nullableDate=null;
```

### Must use `var`:

When you use an anonymous type, or a generic type with one or more type parameters that are anonymous types.

```
var stuff = new {Name="Bob", Age=25};
var bunchOfStuff = from item in items select new {item.Name, item.Age};
```

### Otherwise

It's a question of style and/or taste

Comment: Another must-use of `var` is in Reflection, when dealing with classes that are not public, hence cannot be directly referenced or cast to a known type.

Comment: @Jimi: Yes, but... Reflection is an `object`-based API. You can say `var myList=Activator.CreateInstance(typeofAListofAnonymousTypes);`, but the static type of `myList` will simply be `object`. The compiler won't let you call `Add` on it unless you cast it to an `IList` first. Yes, I usually use `var` with Reflection, but I also use it with strings.

Comment: Not what I meant: take the [`ExtractSslProtocol` snippet  from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48589590/which-tls-version-was-negotiated?answertab=active#tab-top) and try to solve it without using the type inference provided by `var`. Those are not `object` types and not anonymous types.

Comment: All the uses of `var` that I see in that sample declare variables of type `reference to object`. The object to which they refer has a full type (just like my `Activator.CreateInstance` example does), but as far as the compiler knows, they are an `object`. The cool thing about `var` isn't that it can declare a variable that can be any type (`object` or `dynamic` are good enough for that), it's that the compiler can deduce the type and properly type the _variable_.

Comment: None of those types are `object`. They're private/internal classes and properties referencing classes that can't be cast to a .Net class.

Answer (score 1):

`var` is **mostly syntactic sugar** however there are times when you **must use `var`** and that's when you assign variables to **anonymous types**.

Anonymous type example:

```
var anonymousType = new { Name = "Mathew", DOB = DateTime.Now };
Console.WriteLine($"{anonymousType.Name} : {anonymousType.DOB}");
```

As far as when to use it otherwise... this is an opinion and or team guideline. There's nothing gained or lost doing it either way. 
That said; here's my opinion.. this question will get put on hold for too broad but in the mean time here's a little something to look at however you choose.

I like `var` but I believe it can be confusing if you're not careful how you name / use variables but... personally I prefer `var`.  It's shorter and can clean up code or make it somewhat shorter. Especially when you have somethin like `Person person = new Person();` There's just too many Person's there for me...  I also like how var mimics the syntax of JavaScript somewhat (although the two declarations are different).

`var` is not different than declaring the type out right so in your question `string x` or `var x` it doesn't matter.  The compiler infers the type that is being assigned and that's what `var` becomes.

I do recommend this... When you declare ANY variables, especially those using `var` I would always name the declaration as close to the type as possible so that it doesn't matter which you choose.  Name the variables correctly and no one should give you a hard time either way... Then again; this is all opinion.

```
var person1 = new Person();
Person person2 = new Person();

var employee1 = new Employee();
Employee employee2 = new Employee();

var employee3 = new Employee();
Person person3 = new Employee();    

person1.Name = "Mathew";
person2.Name = "Mark";

employee1.Name = "Luke";
employee2.Name = "John";
employee3.Name = "Acts";

person3.Name = "Romans";
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for `var`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var) says:

> An implicitly typed local variable is strongly typed just as if you had declared the type yourself, but the compiler determines the type.

In the end, there is functionally no difference. So, to answer your question, no, it doesn't matter which one you use. And it is for that very reason that there is no "standard" or "proper" one to use.

Use what you prefer.