# How to install NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

How can I install NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio 2010?

I have already tried two options, but they haven't worked.

**Firstly**, I attempted to install nuget.tools from this URL: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NuGetTeam.NuGetPackageManager.
However, I received this error message

```
2/17/2023 11:24:03 AM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
2/17/2023 11:24:03 AM - -------------------------------------------
2/17/2023 11:24:03 AM - vsixinstaller.exe version:
2/17/2023 11:24:03 AM - 17.4.2120
2/17/2023 11:24:03 AM - -------------------------------------------
2/17/2023 11:24:03 AM - Command line parameters:
2/17/2023 11:24:03 AM - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\ServiceHub\Services\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Service\VSIXInstaller.exe,C:\Users\xxxx\Downloads\NuGet.Tools (2010).vsix
2/17/2023 11:24:03 AM - -------------------------------------------
2/17/2023 11:24:03 AM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
2/17/2023 11:24:03 AM - -------------------------------------------
2/17/2023 11:24:04 AM - Initializing Install...
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM - Extension Details...
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -     Identifier         : NuPackToolsVsix.Microsoft.67e54e40-0ae3-42c5-a949-fddf5739e7a5
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -     Name               : NuGet Package Manager
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -     Author             : Microsoft Corporation
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -     Version            : 2.8.60318.667
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -     Description        : A collection of tools to automate the process of downloading, installing, upgrading, configuring, and removing packages from a VS Project.
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -     Locale             : en-US
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -     MoreInfoURL        : http://docs.nuget.org/
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -     InstalledByMSI     : False
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -     SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.0,4.5]
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM - 
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -     SignatureState     : ValidSignature
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -     SignedBy           : Microsoft Corporation
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -     Certificate Info   : 
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -         -------------------------------------------------------
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -         [Subject]       : CN=Microsoft Corporation, OU=MOPR, OU=OPC, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -         [Issuer]        : CN=Microsoft Code Signing PCA, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -         [Serial Number] : 33000000CC776171D4B17BA1280001000000CC
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -         [Not Before]    : 4/23/2014 1:39:04 AM
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -         [Not After]     : 7/23/2015 1:39:04 AM
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -         [Thumbprint]    : 9DD77A79F7124D8DB128A526833CF3760FCB7794
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM - 
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -     Supported Products : 
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -             Version : [10.0,11.0)
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -             ProductArchitecture : x86
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -             Version : [11.0,12.0)
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -             ProductArchitecture : x86
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntegratedShell
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -             Version : [10.0,11.0)
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -             ProductArchitecture : x86
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntegratedShell
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -             Version : [11.0,12.0)
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -             ProductArchitecture : x86
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.VWDExpress
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -             Version : [10.0,11.0)
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -             ProductArchitecture : x86
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.VWDExpress
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -             Version : [11.0,12.0)
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -             ProductArchitecture : x86
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.VPDExpress
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -             Version : [11.0,12.0)
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -             ProductArchitecture : x86
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSWinExpress
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -             Version : [11.0,12.0)
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -             ProductArchitecture : x86
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSWinDesktopExpress
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -             Version : [11.0,12.0)
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -             ProductArchitecture : x86
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM - 
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -     References         : 
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM - Signature Details...
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM -     Extension is signed with a valid signature.
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM - 
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM - Searching for applicable products...
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM - Found installed product - Visual Studio Professional 2022
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM - Found installed product - Visual Studio Professional 2019
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM - Found installed product - Global Location
2/17/2023 11:24:05 AM - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableDataImpl(IInstallableExtension extension, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableData(String vsixPath, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.IsExtensionPack(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.ExpandExtensionPackToInstall(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

**Secondly**, I tried to install it from the Extension Manager,
but I received the error message

```
Cannot search for online extensions because an error occurred while trying to contact the server
```

None of the online forums I have found have been able to help with these two issues.

Comment: It's probable that the package manager simply isn't made to go with Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: I'm guessing using a newer editor isn't possible?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, Actually, that package manager is for Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Good point. Now that I'm looking at it more carefully, it looks like the installer isn't finding Visual Studio 2010 installed on your machine, even though it's finding the other more modern versions. I almost hate to ask, because it seems obvious, but: do you have Visual Studio 2010 installed?

Comment: The following may (or may not) be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859148/cannot-connect-to-any-online-resource

Comment: According to [Visual Studio 2010 Lifecyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/visual-studio-2010), Visual Studio 2010 is no longer supported.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, yes , I have VS2010 in my pc.

Comment: @user09938, the one that you shared doesn't work for me, as I checked.

Comment: For the part you've labeled "Secondly", make a backup copy of `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config`, then modify it as mentioned in the first section of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74800036/10024425) (ie: add the XML to the file as described). You'll most likely find that the location (ie: URL) no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

1.Download NuGet.Tools.vsix.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NuGetTeam.NuGetPackageManager

2.Drag and drop the vsix file to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\VSIXInstaller.exe.