# "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" for SOAP request

Tags: c#, .net, http, ssl, soap

"Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" error when trying to send SOAP request to external API.

The same request is working using SoapUI but failing using .Net Framework 4.6.2 application.
Also, my request has attached X509Certificate, but the same error raises with or without the certificate attached to the request.

I tried using different versions of .Net: .Net Framework 4.8.1 and .Net 6.0. Still the same response.

Also, I tried using different versions of the TLS communication combining with `ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;`:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

For Tls12 and Tls11 server response is the same, but for Tls13 and Ssl3 it says "**Win32Exception: The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm**" which I believe means that I should have been using Tls12 and Tls11 protocols.

I tried overloading ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback and now it always returns true.

Finally, I tried setting up the "SchUseStrongCrypto" flag to "1" but it hadn't helped at all.

[SchUseStrongCrypto flag script screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8nNZ.png)

Comment: What OS are you using? The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70674920/10024425 and [Transport Layer Security (TLS) best practices with the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls)

Comment: @user246821 I'm using Windows 10 22H2, so Win7 recommendations are not relevant for me (?)

Comment: Not true. One can use the same process to enable TLS 1.3 in Win10. In the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70674920/10024425), replace _TLS 1.2_ with _TLS 1.3_.

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Network Tracing in the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/network-tracing)

Comment: @user246821 I did this and enabled TLS 1.3. Now it's actually all the same, but when I'm changing the communication protocol in the code (`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;
`) it says not the old error but "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" as it was for Tls12 and Tls11 before the changes

Comment: Did your read the post _Transport Layer Security (TLS) best practices with the .NET Framework_ mentioned in my first comment? Did you enable _Network Tracing_ as in my last comment? See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74800036/10024425).

Comment: Try using _.NET Framework 4.8_ and remove code that specifies _SecurityProtocol_ (ie: `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol...`).

Comment: @user246821 
1) using .Net Framework 4.8 + removing SecurityProtocol + specifying didn't help
2) Enabled Network Tracing, but I'm not seeing anything interesting in the logs that can help identify the problem. Only possible hook is "Left with 0 client certificates to choose from." log, but I'm not sure
3) Yes, I checked the Microsoft post about TLS best practices, and nothing works for me (or I'm doing something wrong).

Comment: Seems like now is the time to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which others can use to re-create the issue that you're facing. What you've provided is far too minimal.

Comment: @user246821 I can do this, but the problem is I cannot share the endpoint I'm sending to. The issue is happening only with this endpoint (but it works through SoapUI), so unlikely someone would be able to reproduce the exact problem without knowing the destination URL. Still can add some code I'm using to send requests.