DotNetShipping GetRates returns no results
I am trying to use the free DotNetShipping library to retrieve rates from FedEx.  I've gotten all of the test credentials from FedEx, and I downloaded some sample code that I'm trying to get working.  Here is my code:
       string fedexKey = "9nbqfLR71E4izdwj"; 
       string fedexPassword = "3SvlwGqXUstxdrCxSXMIgXzeK"; 
       string fedexAccountNumber = "510087720"; 
       string fedexMeterNumber = "259501201"; 

       // Setup package and destination/origin addresses
       var packages = new List<Package>();
       packages.Add(new Package(12, 12, 12, 35, 150)); // Length, Width, Height, Weight, Insured Value
       packages.Add(new Package(4, 4, 6, 15, 250)); // Length, Width, Height, Weight, Insured Value

       var origin = new DotNetShipping..Address("Chicago", "IL", "60601", "US"); // City, State, Postal Code, Country Code
       var destination = new DotNetShipping.Address("New York", "NY", "10001", "US"); // US Address

       // Create RateManager
       var rateManager = new RateManager();

       // Add desired DotNetShippingProviders
       rateManager.AddProvider(new FedExProvider(fedexKey, fedexPassword, fedexAccountNumber, fedexMeterNumber, false));

       // Call GetRates()
       Shipment shipment = rateManager.GetRates(origin, destination, packages);

       SqlCommand sqlCmd2 = new SqlCommand();
       DataTable table = new DataTable();
       table.Columns.Add("MyRate", typeof(string));
       foreach (Rate rate in shipment.Rates)
       {
           DataRow tableRow = table.NewRow();
           tableRow["MyRate"] = rate.ToString();
           table.Rows.Add(tableRow);
       }
       Repeater2.DataSource = table;
       Repeater2.DataBind();

I'm trying to bind the results to a repeater control, but no results come back - there are 0 rows in the result.   I don't get an error either.  I can't figure out how to get information back that will give me a clue as to what I am doing wrong.  Any advice is greatly appreciated.

According to the DotNetShipping Project Website: This repository is no longer actively maintained. For an updated and maintained version, please visit the following fork:
https://github.com/alexeybusygin/ShippingRates This information can be found by visiting the NuGet page for DotNetShipping and clicking on Project website.

Thank you!  I swapped out the DotNetShipping library for the ShippingRates library, but the same thing is happening.  ShippingRates has some error trapping available as well, but it is returning no errors either, so I'm still stuck at the same place.

spoke too soon, there is an InternalErrors in the ShippingRates library which reveals additional information about what is happening, and it looks like I have an SSL issue going on - my connection is being rejected because - Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'wsbeta.fedex.com'  Thanks for pointing me to the ShippingRates library - that helped greatly!  Thank you!

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74800036/10024425 particularly the last part of the post about how to enable TLS 1.3. Also see Transport Layer Security (TLS) best practices with .NET Framework or  TLS/SSL best practices

Thank you very much!  I ended up solving the problem by adding this:  System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

In the referenced articles(s), in my previous comments, it states NOT to specify the TLS version (as you mentioned in your previous comment), but rather let the OS choose. Unfortunately, you haven't   mentioned the OS version or the .NET version or .NET Framework version that you're using which are important pieces of information.

It's Windows 10 and .NET 4.8
