# How to check the Protocol is being used in a HTTPRequest using C#

Tags: c#, httprequest

I'm trying to figure out how in C# how I can work-out what Protocol version is being used when I make request to a web site/service with a HTTPRequest object.

I know I can define which protocol I'm trying to use with `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` but what I'm trying to get at is what Protocol was used by the website/service, in the same way that I can check using things like Chrome/Firefox under the connection I can see say Protocol version: TLSv1.2

I assume it must be possible, but I'm struggling to find it.  I looked into `ProtocolVersion` but that is not the same, it's either 1.0 or 1.1

Comment: Does this question help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48589590/which-tls-version-was-negotiated ?

Comment: Yep that would do it, though there might be an easier method, but hey.