# how to check if URL is HTTP or HTTPS in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I need to check if a given URL (which is not necessarily prefixed with http or https) is HTTP or HTTPs.

Is this possible in vb.net ?

If the user gives just stackoverflow.com without any prefix, I must be able to identify that it is an HTTP one

Comment: Well, `stackoverflow.com` is *a HTTPS* :) You don't know what protocol will be determined and if you'll be redirected to a HTTPS resource, even if the HTTP protocol is specified in an URI. You have to go for it and see the URI of the Response. Is there a reason why you'd like to know this in advance?

Comment: see this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.issecureconnection?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: What should I see there? As mentioned, you have to establish a connection and see what happens. See also: [Which TLS version was negotiated?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48675492/7444103)

Comment: you can Create code to System.Web library

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what that means.

Comment: you can use this library System.Web

Comment: To do what, exactly? If you need to better qualify your question, click the `edit` link and add more information about your requirements or what you want to achieve. -- As mentioned, you cannot determine off-line the protocol which will be used in a Connection to a remote resource, if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

In case that the url is plain without http/https check it with the below code:

```
    'Validates a URL.
    Function ValidateUrl(url As String) As Boolean
        Dim validatedUri As Uri = Nothing
        If (Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.Absolute, validatedUri)) Then
            Return (validatedUri.Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttp Or validatedUri.Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
        End If
        Return False
    End Function
```

And then do something if http/https exists:

```
Dim u as new System.Uri("http://www.hello.com")
If u.Scheme = "http" Then
   ..do something..
Else
   ..do something else..
```

Comment: That doesn't consult the server to find out if the protocol should be http or https.