# Is posibble to log the TLS version of an Https Request on asp mvc web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ssl

i need to know if there is an easy way to get the SSL/TLS version that is being used in HtppRequest.

I have tried to get if there is a property or if i can get the raw data (the info about the connection), but I didn't find anything.

I need to log the Tls or ssl version that was negotiated during HandShake.
Thank you!

Comment: Maybe this SO question can give you more information:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48589590/which-tls-version-was-negotiated/48675492](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48589590/which-tls-version-was-negotiated/48675492)

Comment: Thank you, but i need to log the data from the HttpRequest that reaches my controller (or Global.asax)