# How to determine which TLS version was negotiated using httpclient in .net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

I found this: [Which TLS version was negotiated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48589590/which-tls-version-was-negotiated)

But I am using http client in .net core. How to determine which tls version was negotiated?

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler which will show the TLS version.

Comment: it is possible when app is deployed to vm but what when I don't have possibility to run app like this. For example in cloud env.

Comment: I think only way is to specify the TLS version.  You can either use 1.2, 1.3, or both : ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;